# how can I make a recursive async function in F#?

Tags: asynchronous, recursion, f#

I have the following:

```
let getCandlesFrom (exchange: IExchange) (instrument: Instrument) (interval: TimeSpan) (fromTime: DateTime) =
    let rec get (c: CandleData array) (f: DateTime) =
        let now = DateTime.UtcNow
        //info $"requesting {f} - {now}"
        let candles = exchange.GetCandles(instrument, interval, f, now)
        if candles.IsError then
            failwith candles.GetError.Describe
        else
            //info $"received data {candles.Get.[0].Timestamp} - {candles.Get.[^0].Timestamp}"
            let c = Array.append c candles.Get
            if c.[^0].Timestamp < now - interval then
                get c (c.[^0].Timestamp + interval)
            else
                c

    get [||] fromTime
```

I would like to move the line:

```
let candles = exchange.GetCandles(instrument, interval, f, now)
```

to an async call:

```
let! candles = exchange.GetCandlesAsync(instrument, interval, f, now)
```

but if I wrap the whole function in an async block, the recursive function doesn't compile and I get this error:

> DataSource.fs(14, 13): [FS0588] The block following this 'let' is unfinished. Every code block is an expression and must have a result. 'let' cannot be the final code element in a block. Consider giving this block an explicit result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't see your code producing the error but you must have forgotten something (after the `let`) - this should work:

```ml
let getCandlesFrom (exchange: IExchange) (instrument: Instrument) (interval: TimeSpan) (fromTime: DateTime) =
    let rec get (c: CandleData array) (f: DateTime) =
        asnyc {
            let now = DateTime.UtcNow
            //info $"requesting {f} - {now}"
            let! candles = exchange.GetCandlesAsync(instrument, interval, f, now)
            if candles.IsError then
                return (failwith candles.GetError.Describe)
            else
                let c = Array.append c candles.Get
                if c.[^0].Timestamp < now - interval then
                    return! get c (c.[^0].Timestamp + interval)
                else
                    return c
    }
    get [||] fromTime
```

notice the `return` and the `return!` for the recursive call - you need those there

Comment: ok, I get it; I didn't do the return! part but now I understand why I need it. Thanks!